# Conditional formatting one cell when all cells in a range have a particular value

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a column A. I want to apply a custom background color to the cell A1 *only* when each cell in the range `C1:T1` contains "Y" (literal letter uppercase Y).

This formatting will be repeated for each row in the sheet.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Please select A1 and apply a Custom formula is of:

```
=countif(C1:T1,"Y")=18
```

Select your background colour.

Either extend the selection range from A1 to suit before the above, change the Apply to range after or copy down to suit.

[COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)

The above assumes `y` treated as `Y` and cell contents of more than a single character (eg "Yes", "YY", "Say" ...) do not count as *contain Y*.